# How to install something that reads from clipboard (like xclip or xsel) without using sudo?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, non-root-user

I want to install `xclip` or `xsel` to a Linux box without using sudo (because its the box is not mine and I am not allowed to sudo). However, I am allowed to use environments or package managers like miniconda or conda. I've been searching the web with no luck though.

Is it possible to install or use such a tool in an easy way (maybe through environments) such that I can copy things to clipboards? I just want to be able to copy paste a document to clipboard (while I am in a ssh connection) and paste it say, in a google doc if I wanted.

I am not in an apple box, so I can't use `pbcopy` I think.

Answer (score 1):

Much of what matters is what dependencies are required for xclip, and whether the libraries it needs are already on these system.

Assuming a  Debian or Ubuntu type system:

You can go to repository that matches your friends machine, download the `.deb` file via a browser.  then use dpkg-deb  to extract the `.deb` into a temporary directory. find the executable and just try it.   If it needs dependencies, you need a lot more effort

Or if you have access to a similar system where it is installed, just copy it from `/usr/bin/xclip` there to a local file on this system

```
cd /tmp
mkdir tryxclip
cd tryxclip
wget http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xclip/xclip_0.12+svn84-4_amd64.deb
dpkg-deb -x xclip*.deb stuff
find stuff -name xclip
```

If you can't use `dpkg-deg`  try `7z` or `ar`

Comment: seems the computer I am on does not let me use `dpkg-deb`...bummer.

Comment: I forget if 7zip undoes `.deb` files.  See if `7z` is there.  The man pages seems to say it does

Comment: it seems `7z`, `7za` nor `7zip` are there. But `unzip` seems to be there.

Comment: Seems like `deb` format is a offshoot of the `ar` format.   Try `ar`

Comment: `7z x xclip.deb`

Comment: `ar` is there! :D

Comment: ok `ar x xclip_0.12+svn84-4_amd64.deb` produced some other files: `control.tar.gz  data.tar.xz  debian-binary`...lets see which one is the one I can use to use xclip.

Comment: You know that file from debian was just an example.  You friend's system could be from an entirely different repository.  like a .386 instead of a amd64, or ubunto, or mint, and a multitude of other distributions